# Unable to change permissions of .pem file used for connecting EC2 instances using WSL2

Tags: amazon-ec2, pem

I have been trying to run these commands but I keep getting permission denied

I tried this `chmod 400 xxxxxx.pem` and with `sudo` too.

The current permissions are -r--r--r-- for the pemfile. Please help. I cannot connect to my EC2 instances without this pem file.

IF i try to connect i get this error

```
Warning: Permanently added 'ec2-x54-xxx-xxx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@         WARNING: UNPROTECTED PRIVATE KEY FILE!          @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
Permissions 0444 for 'xxxxxx.pem' are too open.
It is required that your private key files are NOT accessible by others.
This private key will be ignored.
Load key "xxxxxx.pem": bad permissions
```

I have tried this on WSL2-ubuntu and git bash.

Comment: Is the file located in a directory that you don't own? Create a new dir, move it there and try again with ```chmod```.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're referencing files in the Windows file system, they do not, by default, retain Linux permissions. However, there's a way to enable that. Edit or create (using `sudo`) `/etc/wsl.conf` and add the following:

```
[automount]
options = "metadata"
```

Close all WSL terminals and open a new one.

**Note:** If the private key is on your Windows filesystem (under /mnt/), You can't modify the permissions of files on Windows's filesystem using chmod on Bash on Ubuntu on Windows. You'll have to copy the private key to your WSL home directory (~) and do it there.

Comment: Thank you. this worked. I moved the file to WSL home directory and i was able to change permissions.

Comment: You are a saver!!! This took me a lot of time to figure out while going crazy.